# Does upgrading resources for RDS postgresql have an effect on query performance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.6

We have RDS PostgreSQL which has been upgraded from a t2.medium to a t2.xlarge instance. The database contains a partitioned table with partial indexing. After upgrading to t2.xlarge, when I am querying the partitioned table,  I am observing **10-13 seconds** delay in receiving query results on  t2.xlarge compared to t2.medium.

Can an upgrade affect the underlying storage of data files?  Do I need to vacuum the database?

I  don't understand, why upgrading the resources for PostgreSQL affects query performance?

Comment: Could location be an issue?  In what region(s) are/were the two instances?  Maybe latency is the culprit here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually its upgraded so there is a single RDS instance in same region.